# How to post on wall of Facebook fan page from external website, of which you are a fan but not an admin

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-page, facebooktoolkit

I'm using an ASP.NET [Facebook Developers Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookToolkit) on an external website, and I'm also the admin of a facebook fan page for the website. Users on my website (may or may not be facebook users) create content articles.

I would like to hook up these articles to the Facebook fan page, so that, when they write the article, then ones with FB accounts can sign into FB and post on the Fan page. I'm sure they would need to be a fan first.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: did you got anything working yet?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Graph api to post on face book wall.Follow this link
[link text](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)

You can publish to the Facebook graph by issuing HTTP POST requests to the appropriate connection URLs above, using an application access token. For example, you can post a new wall post on Arjun's wall by issuing a POST request to https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```

I hope it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I really needed this too. So far to me it seems the best way is to embed a native Fan Page and extend it with a Facebook app. This is the only info I ended up with:
http://blogote.com/2010/ideas/how-to-ideas/how-to-embed-facebook-fan-page-on-website-blogs.html

Also have you checked out how GrooveShark does something similar? They embed a Facebook page right into their site for the public. Really sweet. I attached a screenshot of it.

[image]